# Why are these questions linked to each other?

Tags: support, links

Very minor thing here. These two questions

- [How can a black hole produce sound?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/48574/how-can-a-black-hole-produce-sound)
- [Why does a window become a mirror at night?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21075/why-does-a-window-at-night-become-a-mirror)

reference each other under the "linked" sidebar. I thought that was curious, since they have nothing to do with one another. I searched both questions, and yet I could not find a link in the posts or comments of either one to the other. Am I just blind?

My (probably wrong) understanding is that a question is listed under "linked" if and only if either there is a link inserted somewhere to that one, or somewhere on that page there is a link back to the question you are looking at.

So, **is this a bug**, or **is there some other mechanism for linking**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was a comment on [the first question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/48574/how-can-a-black-hole-produce-sound), now deleted, which linked to [the second question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21075/why-does-a-window-at-night-become-a-mirror). That's why those questions were added to each others' Linked sidebars in the first place. As for why the links are still there, I can only imagine that the list of linked questions is cached, and the cache has not been updated in the past few days since the comment was deleted. I'm not sure whether that is the expected behavior or not.

As far as I know, your understanding of the linking mechanism is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The "Linked" sidebar lists all the other questions for which

- there is an outgoing link in to the question, answers or comments.
- there is an incoming link in from the question, answers or comments.

So the only way to know is to find the link that genertated the entry in the Linked sidebar and understand the context. Users being users these will often be relevant but *could* be really off the wall.

---

Hmmm...so far I haven't found such a link.

OK, now I've searched the respective page sources and still not found the link. Very interesting.

Comment: It's in a deleted comment on the question.